# C# .NET 5 Break beam sensor Raspberry PI

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot

I've started a project to counter objects on a production line using a break beam sensor with the Raspberry Pi and Visual Studio Code. I have a python script that works however I need to do it in C#. Currently my code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Threading;

Console.WriteLine("Break Beam. Press Ctrl+C to end.");
int pin = 17;
using var controller = new GpioController();
controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Output);
bool BeamBroke = true;
while (true)
{
   controller.Write(pin, ((BeamBroke) ? PinValue.High : PinValue.Low));
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   BeamBroke = !BeamBroke;
}
```

The problem is that when I run this console app nothing is written about the beam being broken. There aren't any errors.

Comment: You're not writing anything to the console, just to an output pin. This should toggle, every second, the value of pin 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to open an input pin with.

```
controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Input);
```

You will also need to register a callback to be triggered upon pin value change.

```
void BeamBreakCallback(object sender, PinValueChangedEventArgs pinValueChangedEventArgs)
{
    BeamBroke = pinValueChangedEventArgs.ChangeType == PinEventTypes.Falling;
}
```

And then register the callback to be called whenever the input value changes on your input pin.

```
controller.RegisterCallbackForPinValueChangedEvent(
    pin,
    PinEventTypes.Falling | PinEventTypes.Rising, // trigger on both rising and falling edges
    BeamBreakCallback
);
```

If you want to write anything to the console you'll need to add something to the callback

```
void BeamBreakCallback(object sender, PinValueChangedEventArgs pinValueChangedEventArgs)
{
    BeamBroke = pinValueChangedEventArgs.ChangeType == PinEventTypes.Falling;

    if (pinValueChangedEventArgs.ChangeType == PinEventTypes.Falling)
        Console.WriteLine("beam broken");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("beam unbroken");
}
```

**Caveat** I've made some assumptions about whether a falling or rising edge represents a broken beam.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried this code and the console prints "Break Beam. Press Ctrl+C to end." and then it stops. Perhaps I need to use "thread.sleep"?

Comment: Add a `Console.Read()` to check for any key press before quitting. There's probably a more elegant way to do it though